# How to properly break words with two <span> elements?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a chatbox where there are two `<span>` elements, one that holds the username and one that holds the message. In the case of a long word in the message, I want to break to the next line, but I am getting some undesirable behavior with the two spans, separated by a colon. See the example below.

[image: Example]

Notice "Username A" sends a long message that needs to be broken on to the next line. However, "A," which part of their username, is broken into the next line. I want it to look more like the message of "UsernameC", where the line is filled to the end of the chat box as far as it can go before breaking onto a new line. The message span is separated using `margin-left`, so I am suspecting the string of characters "A:longlonglonglonglonglonglong" is being treated as one word, leading to unintended behavior. I do not wish to add any unnecessary spaces after the username or before the message to try to work around this problem. What would be a better way to go about achieving my desired behavior?

```css
.chatbox {
  outline: 1px solid;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.message {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

.text {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chatbox">
  <div class="message">
    <span class="username">Username A</span>:<span class="text">longlonglonglonglonglonglong</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="chatbox">
  <div class="message">
    <span class="username">Username B</span>:<span class="text">long long long long long long long</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="chatbox">
  <div class="message">
    <span class="username">UsernameC</span>:<span class="text">longlonglonglonglonglonglong</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qzw3r9vf/)

Comment: You maybe need `<wbr>` tag? You can put it after `:`. Hope this helps

Comment: @JonNezbit Neat idea, I didn't know about `<wbr>`. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work perfectly as if forces the message onto the next line instead of next to the username. https://jsfiddle.net/oj5Lgtyn/

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `overflow-wrap: break-word` use `line-break: anywhere`.

```css
.chatbox {
  outline: 1px solid;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.message {
  line-break: anywhere;
}

.text {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chatbox">
  <div class="message">
    <span class="username">Username A</span>:<span class="text">longlonglonglonglonglonglong</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="chatbox">
  <div class="message">
    <span class="username">Username B</span>:<span class="text">long long long long long long long</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="chatbox">
  <div class="message">
    <span class="username">UsernameC</span>:<span class="text">longlonglonglonglonglonglong</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Huh handy. Is that a fairly new css feature? I haven't been keeping up with css upgrades lately, just know it has been getting far more robust

Comment: @charlietfl - Not sure. According to caniuse, `line-break`'s been around at least since IE6. The `anywhere` value for it seems to have been introduced in the 2017 CSS Text Level 3 Draft.

Comment: Yeah sorry... I meant the "anywhere", don't remember seeing that one ever. Mention of IE6 made me cringe. I started web work around IE5/6 transition. Used to be a site called iehacks would dig into to to stick in ie conditional comments  for compatibility with FF .. prior to Chrome

Comment: @charlietfl - Yup, been there. NN3 and IE4 was about where I started. IE6 was awesome compared to Netscape Navigator 3.

Comment: Is there any way to preserve the behavior in the "Username B" scenario? "long" is broken in the middle, and I would only want to break a word in the middle if it is too long to fit on one line.

Comment: @wahoowa - The problem you've got is that "A:longlong..." etc. is seen as one word, so if you want spaces to break at all, the line will break before the "A". So I think it's only possible if it's OK to stop the username from breaking on its internal spaces. If that's OK, then you can use `.message { overflow-wrap:break-word; }` with `.username { white-space:nowrap; }`

Answer (score 0):

Replace all the spaces in the usernames with non-breaking spaces: `Username&nbsp;A`. This preserves the behavior you had for B and obviously C (which has no spaces).

```css
.chatbox {
  outline: 1px solid;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.message {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

.text {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chatbox">
  <div class="message">
    <span class="username">Username&nbsp;A</span>:<span class="text">longlonglonglonglonglonglong</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="chatbox">
  <div class="message">
    <span class="username">Username&nbsp;B</span>:<span class="text">long long long long long long long</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="chatbox">
  <div class="message">
    <span class="username">UsernameC</span>:<span class="text">longlonglonglonglonglonglong</span>
  </div>
</div>
```